# Почему импортируемый пакет bukkit горит красным?

Tags: intellij-idea, импорт, minecraft, bukkit

Скачал чужую работу, была только папка src. Открыл через Idea, но пакеты bukkit и kyori горят красным.
Пытался добавить зависимость через *Project Structure -> Libraries*, но не понял, а что именно добавлять то. Так же добавлял *Minecraft* через *Project Structure -> Facets*.
Вот эти пакеты горят красным, а именно слова **bukkit** и **kyori**.

```
import org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import net.kyori.adventure.bossbar.BossBar;
import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component;
import net.kyori.adventure.text.minimessage.MiniMessage;
import net.kyori.adventure.title.Title;
```

Comment: А у вас есть опыт программирования на Java? «Горят красным» - нет подключенных пакетов в classpath. Ищите пакеты в сети. Вот, например: https://github.com/KyoriPowered/adventure/tree/main/4/api/src/main/java/net/kyori/adventure/title